# How can I create an object using the content inside a variable in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Consider I have a variable `class_name`. `class_name` can hold string values like `blog`, `comment` etc. based on the value inside `class_name` I need to create respective object.

If `class_name` is `blog`, I need to create a blog object. How can I achieve this without using a switch?

Comment: Could you explain why you want to do this and maybe even show us some code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd use the [`camelize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-camelize) and [`constantize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-constantize) methods thusly:

```
klass = class_name.camelize.constantize
thing = klass.new
```

If you started with `'blog'` in `class_name`, your `klass` would end up as `Blog`. If your string is actually `'Blog'`, then:

```
klass = class_name.constantize
thing = klass.new
```

Both `camelize` and `constantize` are Rails-specific but I see the "ruby-on-rails" tag so we're in Rails-land.

Comment: I was expecting it to work on rails but I never thought there would be a rails functions. Thanx, This is exactly what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use Kernel.const_get but case is important.

```
a = 'Blog'
b = Kernel.const_get(a).new
```

Comment: Technically [`const_get` is in Module](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M000485) but the low-level classes are all mixed together so close enough.